# How to monitor TLB misses (windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, caching, tlb

Is there a way in windows to monitor the TLB misses of an application? The resource monitor in windows shows me 0 Hard faults/sec (so, TLB misses where the page isn't in main memory). But is there also some way to monitor TLB misses where the page is in main memory?

I have an app where I need to make random accesses across about 100GB of data. I'm running it on a computer with 160GB of ram and am keeping all the data in the working set. Still, what I'm seeing is that during the sections where the random access happens the CPUs are shown in windows task manager to only run at about 20% load (the app is multi-threaded with as many threads as there are cpu cores, without any critical sections and with no I/O).

I'm currently suspecting TLB misses to be the problem and wonder how I could confirm/reject this theory.

Comment: You might be able to measure this with AMD's [uProf tool](https://developer.amd.com/amd-uprof/).  It can measure a number of low-level performance parameters.